# w3 total cache - Object Caching 2165/2469 objects?

Tags: cache, plugin-w3-total-cache, oop

Site is: http://kremim.com

WordPress 3.2.1 MS, buddypress,bbpress installed. wp_options have 333 records. But Object Caching 2165/2469 objects? Why 2000+ ?

Debug:
http://www.unsalkorkmaz.com/problems/kremim_debug.txt
lots of notoptions:options , alloptions:options ? whats those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put - not everything in object cache is an option. Many other things, such as fetching posts or results of resource-intensive function calls, are also cached in there.

I am not sure about meaning of that naming scheme, but [according to plugin's author](https://twitter.com/#!/w3edge/status/125599739264761858) that seems to be normal operation.